# Почему не приходят регистрационные письма зарегистрированных пользователей на почту?

Tags: wordpress, плагин, email

Есть сайт на wordpress с установленным плагином [Theme My Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/) последних версий. На странице регистрации при попытке пользователя зарегистрироваться не приходит письмо активации на почтовый ящик (пробовал, как тестовые, так и gmail), хотя после введенных данных показывается стандартные

> Регистрация прошла успешно, но прежде чем войти, вам необходимо
>   подтвердить свой адрес e-mail. Пожалуйста, проверьте свою почту и
>   перейдите по ссылке в письме.

Ошибок при этом не наблюдаю. С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 1):

В современном мире все письма надо отправлять через проверенные SMTP-сервера, например, smtp.yandex.ru, smtp.google.com. Так как хостинг-провайдеры могут заблокировать РНР функцию `mail()`, например, причин такому масса или ваши письма тупо падают в спам за неверную настройку. Для использования этих SMTP от yandex или google достаточно завести себе почтовый ящик у соответствующего провайдера.

Чтобы настроить все это добро в WordPress, рекомендую плагин [WP Mail SMTP](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/)